# Can I comment on my own question asking people to vote more?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

I'm inquiring about this question:

[In the Netflix Daredevil series, is the "Black Sky" concept from any comic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/in-the-netflix-daredevil-series-is-the-black-sky-concept-from-any-comic)

It is the highest-view question so for this year by a margin of 26,000 (over double the next-highest view count this year). Of those top-ten, it has the second-*lowest* score (9 compared to 6). I made [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/307453/top-viewed-questions-of-2015). It's also #9 in views when you include 2014, despite being only 10 days old, and again second-lowest in score (tied at 9, compared to 5).

I realize my question is probably bringing a lot of traffic straight from Google, and so the views aren't necessarily from the community. As such, they aren't creating account with which to vote.

Nevertheless, it's disappointing to me (as a relatively new user), to see my question so lowly voted, when it's clear people want to see what was asked. I've received no feedback as to how to improve my question (it's pretty straightforward), but I would welcome it.

So, would it be appropriate for me to comment on my own question asking new visitors to take the time to register if they found the question and/or answers helpful, so that they vote?

I'm not looking for a rep-gain here (getting a Gold "Famous Question" badge was more than I ever expected!). I mainly use Parenting.SE, where voting is typically much more active for questions and answers with high views. I realize there are far fewer questions to focus attention on in the Parenting Beta.. I'm trying to wrap me head around the differences.

Comment: You're welcome to ask. I suspect that it won't work.

Comment: @Richard I suspect as much, too. I'm more concerned about whether or not it's tacky than if it's effective, I suppose.

Comment: I wouldn't see it as tacky.

Comment: Commenting on the question is unlikely to do much of anything as it doesn't bump the question and many users don't read the comments.

Comment: @phantom42 The question is still receiving thousands of views a day, so it's still getting visibility. I think that it being the *only* comment would make it visible, as well.

Comment: I personally find that sort of comment annoying, but I know it's not universal.  In the past I've sometimes flagged similar comments as being "too chatty" (they don't add anything to the question), but I don't know if anyone else does.

Comment: My personal opinion is that it is tacky. Additionally,  I doubt you'll see many extra upvotes, as like you said many of the results are from google. And most people who didn't see it worthy of an upvote won't change their mind if they see a comment about it.

Comment: Based on these responses I'm opting not to leave any comment, although i did edit the question to make it a little prettier and clearer.

Comment: There is also a rep requirement to voting, so even if the people did take the time to register (which I think is unlikely) they couldn't vote for your question.

Comment: @TZHX Wow, I never realized that. My first rep-goal was commenting, I didn't realize I couldn't vote until 15 rep. Great point, and further proof that it would have been patently ineffective.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, my personal opinion is that it is tacky, though there is nothing *prohibiting* you from doing so (site policy, etc). However, while my initial reaction is that you were overreacting, I checked the query you posted and decided to look at [questions in general for the year](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/edit/307780). And I was quite surprised.

Graphing the questions for the year *with* your question, I get this data:

[image]

Graphing the questions for the year *without* your question, I get this data:

[image]

Your question changes the slope of the data by 25% and the R-squared value, which tells you how strongly correlated the data is, without your question is at 0.73, but *with* your question is a much lower 0.57.

**BUT...this is for just this year, which is only 4 months old.**

So I ran the query for the entire history of SE (using the same query, but with a start date of 1 Jan 2011), and got a much larger data set (over 20,000 data points). I graphed this as well, and as you can see, there's a lot more outliers.

[image]

Your question is the one highlighted in red in the lower left-hand corner. As you can see, there are a significant number of questions in the area right around yours that have similar votes-to-views ratio. Some have less votes with a similar number of views. But if you look at the overall picture, the data is significantly more random. The R-squared value drops to 0.14, a value meaning there is little correlation between views and votes. Your question is no longer an extreme outlier, in fact, I've noted several questions of interest on the chart:

- (A) is [In the Walking Dad, what did Dr. Jenner tell Rick?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22079/in-the-walking-dead-what-did-dr-jenner-tell-rick). It has 206,308 views - some 5 times your question, and yet only has *8 upvotes*.
- (B) is, coincidentally, also about the Walking Dead - [How did the Zombies infection start in the Walking Dead?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11325/how-did-the-zombies-infection-start-in-the-walking-dead). It actually has the *most views of any question* - 408,659. And it only has 30 upvotes.

Then we see some that are the opposite.

- (C) has the most upvotes of any question - [Would the One Ring even work for anyone but Sauron?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48180/would-the-one-ring-even-work-for-anyone-but-sauron?s=1%7C3.5309). With 38,148 views, it has 236 upvotes.
- (D) is similar - also a Tolkien question - [Who or what was Tom Bombadil?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/who-or-what-was-tom-bombadil?s=1%7C3.8648). It has only 21,995 views and 226 upvotes.

And for fun, we see the most "extreme" example that fits the trendline:

- (E) [In what order should the Star Wars movies be watched?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched?s=1%7C2.8503) - 341,264 views, 167 upvotes.

**So there's not a huge correlation historically between views and votes. Your question is not the first, nor will it be the last.** I *suspect* that over time, you'll pick up some more upvotes with the views, but it's not unheard of for questions to perform like yours. Given how other questions are similarly received, I doubt that any plea for more votes would be particularly effective.

As you noted, a lot of your views are probably drive-by views from Google, who can't upvote anyway. From some of the examples that are similar, they likely recieve a lot of drive-by views but not votes, because the topic is popular at the time.

*Anecdotally, I found it interesting that the "worst performing" questions were [the-walking-dead](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead) and the "best performing" questions were [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings)/[tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien). If people are interested, I'd be happy to analyze the behavior of different tags and how that affects votes when I have the time.*

Comment: This is the perfect information, and exactly what I didn't know I wanted. I'm not brushed up on my Stats material, so I wasn't sure how to make a meaningful analysis of the site's trends as a whole. So, I take from this: 1) Yes, some people will think it's tacky 2) It's statistically going to be ineffective 3) My view-to-votes is only an outlier in the recent history.

Comment: Also, yes, seeing a correlation between tags and voting behavior would be phenomenal. I have a feeling that popular movies/TV shows are going to have lower votes-to-views, because of increased traffic from off-site.

Comment: @CreationEdge - yes, I'd say that's accurate. I'll work up the analysis when I have time, but that's probably true.

Comment: " I'd be happy to analyze the behavior of different tags" - probably worth making a blog post and making our resident fish-killing unicorn blood drinker happy

Comment: @DVK - I was going to write a separate meta post but I guess I could do a blog post

Comment: Do you have a link to these queries?

Comment: @curiousdannii - I added a link to the first query, the second is only a modification of the date parameter of the first one.

Comment: +1 for maths. I have no idea what it means, but it's very shiny.

Comment: Was checking this out again because of chat, and I notice that (E) is now 572K, trumping (B) by far, and most likely due to The Force Awakens.

Answer (score 5):

I feel for you in what you are asking ... more voting. I wish more voting was done throughout SE. Everyone has 40 votes per day, why not use them? The problem is, begging for votes isn't going to help you or your question. I have seen it happen on SE ... when I do, I *intentionally* don't vote it up no matter how good it is, and I'm a prolific voter.

Unfortunately, IMHO, you just need to let your question ride. Enjoy the fact you gained a gold badge from it due to it's popularity. Those don't come along that often ... unless your user name is Richard ;-)

Comment: Again, I want to make it clear that I wouldn't have been begging. I'm completely satisfied with the current results, I was just wondering if it were possible to increase engagement. I felt that the answers deserved more attention IMHO. On Parenting, we've had lower quality answers get much better voting participation. Answer votes on our higher view count questions usually outstrip the question votes (although I'd need to run queries to prove this).

Comment: @CreationEdge - I realize your intention is not to beg ... but, unfortunately, that's how it appears. Appearances and perceptions overrule intentions on the internet, as you are probably well aware.

Comment: @Paulster2 - Begging for upvotes is sooo tacky (he says, checking his rep for the day)

Answer (score 3):

Commenting on your question to ask people to vote for it would not be allowed, polite, or effective.

You can read [what comments are for](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) in the help center. The purpose of comments is to do something that, ideally, should lead to an edit of the post, such as requesting clarification or pointing out something that could be improved. A comment becomes obsolete when the post is updated accordingly or when the proposed change turns out not to be warranted.

Pushing people to vote for your stuff is tacky in most social settings, including this community.

If your question is getting a lot of views but few upvotes, it means that it's being seen from people from outside the SFF.SE community, who cannot vote here. It's likely that it's been linked in some high-traffic community. There's no point in telling people to do something that they cannot do.

Comment: Were I to have done it, it wouldn't have been to just blatantly ask people to vote for *me*, but to inform users that if they find questions and/or answers on the site helpful, that they can very quickly create accounts and contribute. I'm aware that most of the traffic was from offsite, so I was trying to think of ways to increase engagement of off-site visitors. Also, in most social settings with voting, it's been my experience that it's *expected* that people actively solicit votes for themselves. StackExchange is the counter, not the norm, so I'm trying to adjust to this local culture.

Comment: @CreationEdge - those kind of comments are better off as just a link to the Tour, and generally directed specifically at new users (e.g. askers and answerers).

Comment: @SSumner Yes, that would be the epitome of what I had in mind. Unfortunately, there aren't specific people to direct to there, so there's no point. Point taken.