# What's the effect of the recent renewed interest in Star Wars on statistics?

Tags: discussion, site-statistics, recent-activity

Not surprisingly, there has obviously been a major uptick in [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars)-related activity as there is renewed interest and presumably as people have been rewatching the *Star Wars* movies leading up to the release of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*.

## Is anyone interested in writing the queries and providing a (possibly ongoing) analysis of the trends of activity on *Star Wars*-related posts?

Comment: I'd consider it once I’ve seen the film; right now I’m maintaining as far a distance as I can from anything to do with the [tag:star-wars] tag.

Comment: @alexwchan that might be best SEDE tends to lag behind.

Answer (score 4):

There has been an awakening<sup>1</sup>.

I'm using [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) as a baseline, because they're my graphs and I want to.

### [Question growth over time](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/410457/ratio-of-questions-with-specific-tag#graph)

[image]

The above graph shows question growth in absolute numbers. *Star Wars* questions (blue line) have been growing more-or-less constantly since July 2012, and slightly slower (at least recently) than *Star Trek* (red line) questions. There is, however, a very slight uptick in the last few days. In the interests of exploring that better, I [modified my query slightly](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/414370/ratio-of-questions-with-specific-tag#graph)

[image]

You can see the *Star Wars* line (now the yellow line, not blue) begin to grow fairly significantly starting on December 17.

### [Percentage Question Growth](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/410461/ratio-of-questions-with-specific-tag#graph)

[image]

The above graph shows the change in percentage of *Star Wars* questions. There has been an uptick, beginning in about August, that got suddenly very large near the end of December. Looking [just for the month of December](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/414373/ratio-of-questions-with-specific-tag#graph), we can see that this very closely resembles the previous graph:

[image]

### [Question Statistics](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/410466/overall-statistics-of-questions-with-specific-tag)

This one is going to be less scientific.

[image]

Compare to my graph from last week:

[image]

And to an analysis I did [in November](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7619/31051):

[image]

We can see that views on *Star Wars* questions have gone up a fair amount in the intervening period, but other statistics have grown only a small bit. Average answer score has actually gone down, which I can only attribute to a sudden influx of low-quality but not-deleteable answers from new users.

There are, of course, always exceptions; all of my numbers here are averages. A particularly extreme example<sup>2</sup> is [In what order should the Star Wars movies be watched?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched), which has gone from [341K views and +167 score in April 2015](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/can-i-comment-on-my-own-question-asking-people-to-vote-more/6864#6864) to 787K views and +190 score at time of writing.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclaimer: at time of writing, SEDE was last updated December 20, so these stats are a few days out of date. I'll revisit this after SEDE updates on December 27, subject to my own schedule

<sup>2</sup> Nod to CreationEdge for pointing out this edge case

Comment: More stats: [This SW question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched) had [341K views in April](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6864/31178) and it grew to [572K in October](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/can-i-comment-on-my-own-question-asking-people-to-vote-more#comment20222_6864) and is now at 786K views. That's a *tremendous* amount of growth for a 4 year old question.

Comment: @CreationEdge That seems like it would be a popular one in the leadup to a new movie. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: have you acounted for some TFA questions lacking [tag:star-wars]?

Comment: @DVK I did not, but there are only [five of them](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-force-awakens+-star-wars), so they wouldn't have much of an effect anyway

Comment: @JasonBaker - makes sense. Seemed a lot more, but I suppose people fixed that via edits

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the tag statistics (as of today, 22 Dec at around 18:30 UTC):

[image]

[story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification): 36 asked this week, 121 this month
[harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter): 13 asked this week, 74 this month
**[star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars): 33 asked today, 194 this week**
[star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek): 11 asked this week, 74 this month
[lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings): 15 asked this week, 49 this month
[movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie): 11 asked this week, 23 this month
[short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories): 16 asked this month, 357 this year
[doctor-who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who): 7 asked this week, 65 this month
[marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics): 22 asked this month, 300 this year
[star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng): 9 asked this week, 36 this month
[tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien): 19 asked this week, 34 this month
[books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books): 5 asked this week, 14 this month
[marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe): 27 asked this month, 392 this year
[game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones): 7 asked this month, 159 this year
[comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics): 7 asked this month, 95 this year
[a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire): 10 asked this month, 137 this year

### There have been more Star Wars questions in the last 7 days than in all the rest of the top 12 tags put together.

Now *that's* what I call a disturbance in the <strike>Force</strike> site!

Comment: Please note that this doesn't even account for the fact that plenty of SW7 questions **are deliberately not being asked yet**. I have a list of about 30 pending questions I have, from watching or reading novelization, and didn't post even one of them because of rep cap.